# Refactoring React Class component to Functional, how to use action creator inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to refactor a class component to functional component and am not convinced by using an action creator inside of `useEffect()` instead of `componentDidMount()` . Essentially my linter doesn't like that I'm not passing `props` in to the second argument of `useEffect()`, but if I do that then the component re-renders infinitely. I've found quite a few answers to similar questions but they mostly just say it's okay to ignore the linter in this kind of case.

*However, what I'd like to know is if this is the actual best way of doing it* - not what will work, or how to ignore the linter, but what I should be doing in a perfect world to achieve the same effect. I'm fairly sure that just ignoring the linter can't be the best answer, but I'm also very new to React so I may well be missing something obvious.

This is my class component:

```
class StreamDelete extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchStream(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.stream.title}</div>
        );
    }
    
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return { stream: state.streams[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStream })(StreamDelete);
```

And this is my functional component:

```
const StreamDelete = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchStream(props.match.params.id);
    }, []) // I've tried passing in props here, but then the component re-renders itself infinitely

    return (
        <div>{props.stream.title}</div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {stream: state.streams[ownProps.match.params.id]}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStream })(StreamDelete);
```

In case it's relevant, this is my action creator:

```
export const fetchStream = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await streams.get(`/streams/${id}`);
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_STREAM,
        payload: response.data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
const id = props.match.params.id;
const { fetchStream } = props;
useEffect(() => {
  fetchStream(id);
}, [fetchStream, id]);
```

If you have a linter you can check for [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense! I guess this way you're only re-rendering if either the fetchStream function or the id change, which should never happen - whereas before it was changing if any prop at all changed. Is that more or less right?

Comment: @Jul Yes, the fetchStream should not change but it's added to satisfy the linter.